# snippets in vs code version 1.13

Tags: visual-studio-code

In 1.13 (and up) version of [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) update there is some problem or change about the behavior of the snippets in vs code that i don't like.

Whenever you  used a snippet in vs code you would could keep press <kbd>tab</kbd>
and vs code would loop over `$1` `$2` placeholders ... and would never get to the `$0` last cursor placeholder.

Now in version 1.13 they have changed something and the `$0` is in the last <kbd>tab</kbd> hit according to the number of placeholders.

I think it is because thay have added `multi-cursor-snippets` or `strict-snippets`
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_strict-snippets

#### Example of how it was before

[image: snippets behavior before -v 1.13]

So my question is do somebody knows how to change it back or it is on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. If you feel the snippet behavior could be improved, please [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new).